# can i change the entry point of an Application

Tags: mfc, entry-point

i have been developing a onscreen keyboard application.

but i have to invoke the same now on the click of a button in another UI.

is it possible to change the entry point of the application to the other Dialog?

or should i start another project

Comment: Why you want to change the entry point?

Answer (score 0):

Arrange for your application to be sent a command line argument to indicate that the caller wants the alternative dialog. When the application starts, it should check for this argument and switch behaviour accordingly.

Note that an application has exactly one entry point so the above is in fact the only solution bar creating separate applications.